# page source doesn't have dynamic div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically adding the content of "div" in jquery it is added in DOM. but in view page source i can't see dynamic content of an element

```
<div id="pdf"></div>

("#btn").click(function(){
$("#pdf").html("ffff");
});
```

how can i get updated page source after made dynamic changes. it is added in DOM but page source doesn't have the content ? why ?

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's just normal behavior, the source is allways the original source of the page and it doesn't show changes made after page load. If you want to check the source after changes use a tool like firebug or chrome developer tools.

EDIT:
As Johannes H stated you no longer require firebug since major browsers all include developer tools.

Comment: Firefox has built-in web developer toos in the latest versions, too, no need for firebug anymore. Internet Explorer has them, too. IN all three browsers (chrome, IE; firefox), F12 will open them.

Answer (score 5):

The page source is the page source - a raw text file which cannot be changed. It is hosted on the server and it's obvious you can't made any changes to it. Once you visit a web page, your browser queries to *read* that text file and then it parses it to the DOM. When you do any javascript/jQuery magic like adding new html elements, you do it on the DOM.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation on what "show source" does and deosn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Firefox you can get the "web developer" plugin, then view "generated source". This will show the jQuery added div.

Answer (score 1):

When You are viewing the page source the javascript will not run, so the dynamic elements will not be added.
To get the sources you can use your browser developer tools:

1. click f12
2. choose the top element and press copy as html.