# How twitter hides their HTML or attributes in view page source (Ctrl + U)?

Tags: html, twitter

I'm just wondering how twitter hides their HTML on Ctrl + U , I know that hiding the HTML is impossible but when i pressed ctrl + u on any twitter account i'll faced these html :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxBJ6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use a framework that injects javascript created elements dynamically, doing this doesn't let you see the elements in the Ctrl+U view but you can see them in the inspector.
Specifically Twitter uses React, link [here](https://stackshare.io/twitter/twitter) for source

Comment: Is there a article about this? I want to know exactly how this can be done

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't find it, but i can link you some other SO questions with the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451554/is-it-correct-that-page-elements-created-by-jquery-do-not-show-up-in-the-source or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832685/page-source-doesnt-have-dynamic-div-element

Comment: @Diok — There's no value in *hiding* the HTML (as pointed out, it shows up in the DOM inspector). It's a (bad) side-effect of being a SPA.