# Page source not showing in next.js Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Page Source not showing in next.js Component which is essential for SEO. Everything is working fine the only problem is the page source as shown in the image attached [image].Here `loading` part is shown in page source. how do I render the final data? I am using useEffect Here to render the data. Kindly Help me out...

```
const SnippetsPaginate = ({ snippetsData }) => {

const snippetMainData = snippetsData.snippets.data;

const [snippets, setSnippets] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        setSnippets(snippetMainData);
        setLoading(false);
},[snippetMainData]);

const router = useRouter();
const handlePagination = page => {
    const path = router.pathname
    const query = router.query
    query.page = page.selected + 1
    router.push({
        pathname: path,
        query: query,
    });
   
}

return (
    <>
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <div className=''>
                <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-5 gap-3 px-4 mx-auto mb-6">
                    <div className="lg:col-span-4">
                        <div className='grid lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2 gap-3 mt-1'>
                            
                            {loading && Array.from({length: 27}, (v,i)=> <SnippetsSkeleton key={i}/>)}

                            {!loading && snippets.map(snippet => (
                                <SnippetsTemplate key={snippet.id}
                                    snippetsDetails={snippet}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </div>
                        <ReactPaginate
                            marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                            pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                            previousLabel={<BsChevronLeft />}
                            nextLabel={<BsChevronRight />}
                            breakLabel={"..."}
                            initialPage={snippetsData.snippets.current_page - 1}
                            pageCount={snippetsData.snippets.last_page}
                            onPageChange={handlePagination}
                            containerClassName={"paginate-wrap"}
                            subContainerClassName={"paginate-inner"}
                            pageClassName={"paginate-li"}
                            pageLinkClassName={"paginate-a"}
                            activeClassName={"paginate-active"}
                            nextLinkClassName={"paginate-next-a"}
                            previousLinkClassName={"paginate-prev-a"}
                            breakLinkClassName={"paginate-break-a"}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </>

  );



 }

 export default SnippetsPaginate;
```

Comment: Are you using this with a service worker? PWA?

Comment: Yeah, Its kind of Progressive Web App.

Comment: Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028991/page-content-is-not-showing-in-source-code

Comment: Perfect!! Can i use React Query Here? How do i show Loader(until content not fetched) here

Comment: You can certainly use React Query, but if the SEO component depends on data you load in the client-side, then you'll still have the same issue. If you want SEO-related data to show in the Page Source, the data needs to be fetched on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

you should not use useEffect to set data that you want to show on your SEO. instead use getStaticProps or getServerSideprops as per your requirement. The problem will be solved