# head tag not appearing in view source : next:js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have created my next js appp where i have implemented my `head` tag but when i check the view source  by right clicking i dont see my title and meta tags there  how can i achive that?

eventhough the head tag is missing in `view souce`  it can be found in `inspect element`

```
<Head>
                <title> {itm.Name} - wixten </title>
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/wixten.png" />
                <meta
                  name="viewport"
                  content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"
                />
                <meta name="description" content={itm.Summary} />
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <meta property="og:title" content={itm.Name} />
                <meta property="og:description" content={itm.Summary} />
                <meta property="og:image" content="images/wixten.png" />
                <meta property="og:locale" key="og:locale" content="en_US" />
                <meta property="og:type" key="og:type" content="website" />
                <meta
                  property="og:url"
                  key="og:url"
                  content={`${baseurl}${itm._id}`}
                />
              </Head>
```

i am adding full code in codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-franklin-gpht9?file=/pages/index.js

the website i am faceing issue is this

https://wixten.com/query/61f4f5f9e41f700023c833c0

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Page Content is not showing in source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028991/page-content-is-not-showing-in-source-code)? You're populating the `<head>` based on data fetched on the client-side. You need to fetch and populate it on the server for it to show in the page source.

Comment: @juliomalves i think ur answer is close to what i want could u pls help me with a working example based on my code

Comment: You'll have to fetch the items on the server-side (`getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`) rather than doing it on the client inside `useEffect`. For more details, I'd recommend you go through the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#two-forms-of-pre-rendering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your title and meta tags aren't appearing in your source code because you're fetching them client-side, after the page loads.

In order to include them in the source code, they need to be fetched ahead of time, either through Server-Side Rendering (SSR) or through Static Site Generation (SSG). The Next docs [cover these options](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview) thoroughly.

Assuming you want to go the SSR route, you'd do the following:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const res = await axios.get(...);

    return {
        // will be passed to the page component as props
        props: {
            Item: res.data
        }, 
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your component like this:

```
function MyPageComponent({ Item }) {
    return (
        <Head>
            <title>{Item.name}</title>
        </Head>
    )
}
```

Comment: Even after using `getStaticProps()` when I right click and view the page source, my title tag and meta tags in the head aren't appearing. I am currently running on the dev environment, might that have anything to do with this?

Comment: @NischayaSharma - It should still work correctly in the dev environment. Are you actually getting your title info in your `getStaticProps()` call?

See the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) for more info.

Comment: There are no calls in `getStaticProps()`, I just wanna load my homepage statically, so that my meta and title tags are visible for the SEO Optimization. The docs say that just adding function to the end of the page before the `export default pagename` will build the HTML and JSON during `next build` and serve the static HTML page.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the docs. Adding getStaticProps() will cause the page to go through the static build process, but if all your info is still loaded client-side it won't make any difference. You need to explicitly define what's loaded server-side (will show up in raw HTML) and what's loaded client-side (will not).

Comment: @mohas - that's just blatantly wrong... Here's what the docs say: "You should use getStaticProps if:

- The data required to render the page is available at build time ahead of a user’s request
- The data comes from a headless CMS
- The page must be pre-rendered (for SEO) and be very fast — getStaticProps generates HTML and JSON files, both of which can be cached by a CDN for performance"

Comment: @Tim yes, I made further investigations and the culprit was authentication context that was doing conditional rendering

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if anyone is facing the same issue like this, please check your _document.jsx to see if it matches the SSR requirements. If it is not set up then the meta tag won't show up.

You would need to include your meta tags there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your head in the return otherwise it won't appear on the client side

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Next.js `Head` to set the title

```
import Head from "next/head";
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>your title</title>
      </Head>
     // code
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: it's not working. I tried this but it's not show the right title

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, re-launching a new tab with localhost:3000 solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this mentioned here, and there are a few other questions on SO that also fail to address the solution that I needed (many reference importing `Head` from the right place, etc.).

All I had to do was change `fallback` to `"blocking"` from `true` in `getStaticPaths`. Immediately resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, Please try to open in another tab or close the browser and try again in case doesn't. I faced same issue. This solution worked for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. You may have to install next-themes npm first like below.

```
npm i next-themes
```

Then, update your `pages\_app.tsx` or similar to have `ThemeProvider` like this

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes'
import '../styles/index.css'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider attribute='class'>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to include them in the source code, they need to be fetched ahead of time, either through Server-Side Rendering (SSR) or through Static Site Generation (SSG). and add

```js
 const defaultTitle = 'Your Default Title';

      // Get the title from the page's props, or use the defaultTitle
      const pageTitle = pageProps?.seoData?.title || defaultTitle;
```

```js
// pages/_app.js
import Head from 'next/head';
import '../styles/globals.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Define a default title that will be used if a page doesn't provide its own title
  const defaultTitle = 'Your Default Title';

  // Get the title from the page's props, or use the defaultTitle
  const pageTitle = pageProps?.seoData?.title || defaultTitle;

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{pageTitle}</title>
        {/* Include any additional global meta tags or stylesheets */}
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```