# OpenGraph with NextSEO - doesn't work for certain page

Tags: next.js, facebook-opengraph

I've been trying to debug this for hours now..

OpenGraph with NextSEO is working on other pages, but not on this page.

I'm loading and passing the variables from getStaticProps to the main component.

```
  return (
    <>
      <NextSeo
        title={`${authorNickname} on Breakout "${postBody}"`}
        description={postBody}
        openGraph={{
          title: `${authorNickname} on Breakout "${postBody}"`,
          description: postBody,
          url: `https://breakout.so/post/${authorNickname}/${activityId}`,
          site_name: "breakout.so",
        }}
      />
      // ... main components
  </>);
```

It has the correct data when I test it through 'local host open graph checker' chrome extension.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
<meta name="description" content="Test post">
<meta property="og:title" content="eric on Breakout &quot;Test post&quot;">
<meta property="og:description" content="Test post">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://breakout.so/post/eric/0f35c9f0-65b6-11ed-8080-80010701c78a">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="breakout.so">
<meta name="next-head-count" content="15"><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
<script src="https://cdn.iubenda.com/iubenda.js"></script>
<script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js?ts=1668606808077"></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1668606808077" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1668606808077" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1668606808077" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/community.js?ts=1668606808077" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js?ts=1668606808077" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js?ts=1668606808077" defer=""></script>
<script src="/_next/static/development/_middlewareManifest.js?ts=1668606808077" defer=""></script>
<style>
```

and it's correctly parsed in https://www.opengraph.xyz.

However, when I try the actual URL (https://www.breakout.so/post/milktea/891ac820-6556-11ed-8080-80001833df7a), it defaults to the title and description in `_app.js`. When I delete them in `_app.js`, it doesn't parse anything.

My code here (some details are omitted. also the commented-out function header and getStaticPaths/Props weren't working either)

```
// export default function PostDetails({ postBody, activityId, authorNickname }) {
export default function PostDetails({}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { activityId, authorNickname } = router.query;
  const [isRoutineSnapshotOpen, setIsRoutineSnapshotOpen] = useState(true);
  const [result] = useQuery({
    query: gql`
      query ($nickname: String, $postId: ID) {
        # query ($nickname: String) {
        user(nickname: $nickname) {
          id
        }
        postDetails(id: $postId) {
          body
          routineSnapshot
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: { nickname: authorNickname, postId: activityId },
    // variables: { nickname: authorNickname },
    pause: !router.isReady,
  });
  const { data, fetching, error } = result;
  if (!data || fetching) {
    return "Loading post details...";
  }
  if (error) {
    return <p>Unexpected error occurred. Try refreshing the page.</p>;
  }
  if (!data?.user) {
    return <p>Couldn't find user {authorNickname}</p>;
  }

  const authorId = data.user.id;
  return (
    <>
      <NextSeo
        title={`${authorNickname} on Breakout ${
          postDetails?.body ? `"${postDetails.body}"` : ""
        }`}
        description={postDetails?.body || ""}
        openGraph={{
          title: `${authorNickname} on Breakout ${
            postDetails?.body ? `"${postDetails.body}"` : ""
          }`,
          description: postDetails?.body || "",
          url: `https://breakout.so/post/${authorNickname}/${activityId}`,
          site_name: "breakout.so",
        }}
      />

      <div className="bg-white px-4 border-none py-2 sm:px-6">
        <SinglePost
          activityId={activityId}
          feedGroup="user"
          userId={authorId}
          Activity={(props) => {
            return useMemo(() => {
              return (
                <Activity
                  {...props}
                  Header={({ activity }) => (
                    <ActivityHeader activity={activity} />
                  )}
                  Content={({ activity }) => (
                    <>
                      <ActivityContent activity={activity} />
                      <div className="">{userInfoAndRoutineSection}</div>
                    </>
                  )}
                  Footer={({ activity }) => (
                    <div>
                      <div className="w-full border-t border-gray-300"></div>
                      <CommentInputField activity={activity} />
                      <CommentList
                        activityId={activity.id}
                        CommentItem={(props) => {
                          const createLinkToProfile = (children) => (
                            <Link
                              href={{
                                pathname: "/u/[nickname]",
                                query: {
                                  nickname: props.comment.user.data.nickname,
                                },
                              }}
                            >
                              {children}
                            </Link>
                          );

                          const taggedUsers = (
                            props.comment.data?.taggedUsers || []
                          ).map((nickname) => `@${nickname}`);
                          const textArray = props.comment.data.text.split(" ");
                          const textWithHighlights = textArray
                            .map((word) => {
                              if (taggedUsers.includes(word)) {
                                return `<span class="text-green-700">${word}</span>`;
                              }
                              return word;
                            })
                            .join(" ");

                          const text = (
                            <div
                              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                __html: `<p>${textWithHighlights}</p>`,
                              }}
                            />
                          );

                          return (
                            <div className="my-2 flex space-x-3">
                              <div className="shrink-0">
                                {createLinkToProfile(
                                  <img
                                    className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full cursor-pointer"
                                    src={props.comment.user.data.image}
                                    alt=""
                                  />
                                )}
                              </div>

                              <div className="text-sm">
                                <div className="p-2 bg-gray-100 rounded-md">
                                  {createLinkToProfile(
                                    <a className="text-gray-900 font-semibold hover:text-violet-600">
                                      {props.comment.user.data.nickname}
                                    </a>
                                  )}
                                  <div className="text-gray-700">{text}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                  <span className="ml-2 text-gray-500">
                                    {formatTimeAgoUtc(props.comment.created_at)}
                                  </span>
                                  {/* <button
                                  type="button"
                                  className="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900"
                                  onClick={() => {}}
                                >
                                  Reply
                                </button> */}
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          );
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  )}
                />
              );

              // [props] or [props.activity] keeps re-rendering it... doesn't really seem to matter so just passing id
            }, [props.activity.id]);
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

// export async function getStaticPaths() {
//   const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
//     include: {
//       user: true,
//     },
//   });

//   // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
//   const paths = posts
//     .filter((post) => post.body)
//     .map((post) => ({
//       params: { authorNickname: post.user.nickname, activityId: post.id },
//     }));

//   // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
//   // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
//   return { paths, fallback: true };
// }

// export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
//   if (!params.authorNickname || !params.activityId) {
//     return { props: {} };
//   }
//   const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
//     where: { id: params.activityId },
//     include: {
//       review: true,
//       routineSnapshot: true,
//     },
//   });

//   return {
//     props: {
//       urqlState: ssrCache.extractData(),
//       postBody: post?.body || post?.review.comment || "",
//       routineSnapshot: post.routineSnapshot,
//       activityId: params.activityId,
//       authorNickname: params.authorNickname,
//     },
//     revalidate: 30,
//   };
// }
```

Comment: When I paste your link into https://www.opengraph.xyz/ it's using the default title. I suspect the issue is when you load your website without javascript it has the default title. In the initial html payload the title is<meta property="og:title" content="breakout.so - Share the full picture of your skin care routine"/>. Why isn't the NextSeo on the inital load? When I copy paste your code above, NextSeo is in the initial load.

Comment: @evandwight There's a chance that it's not in the initial load because I switched the `postBody` data loading from loading and passing props from `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` to dynamically querying it through GraphQL since asking the question. However, I think this was the case when I used `getStaticProps` too.

Comment: Also, I tried removing all dynamic data from my opengraph args and just using static strings like 'test', and it's still not working.

Comment: The issue isn't the dynamic args. The issue is your NextSeo component isn't being rendered in the initial html. It starts as `<meta property="og:title" content="breakout.so - Share the full picture of your skin care routine"/>` and then the javascript loads and changes it to `<meta property="og:title" content="test">`.  Facebook and opengraph are just looking at the initial html. They arent running any javascript. Can you post the code for entire page?

Comment: Thanks. I copied and pasted the code in the main body. @evandwight

Comment: On first load you are rendering `"Loading post details..."`. There is no SEO information. You need to use getServerSideProps so the first load has the SEO information.

Comment: That's because your client-side data fetching is preventing the metadata to be rendered on the server, it won't be available to crawlers if it's not present on the server response (see page source). Fetch the data on the server using `getStaticProps` instead. See [Page content is not showing in page source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028991/page-content-is-not-showing-in-page-source).