# Open Graph not displaying properly on Twitter

Tags: html, twitter, next.js, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I run a job board and when my Twitter Bot ( https://twitter.com/ecomjobs_ ) posts the jobs on its page, the Twitter display card is still the default Open Graph.

I've tried every fix under the sun for this but can't get my Twitter Card to show the right information (Title, Description, etc)

Here is my website: https://ecom-jobs.com. If you select a job, take that URL, and try to share it on Twitter it always shows the default Open Graph card.

You can check the meta tags and see both the og and twitter card tags are written properly. I had also read that Twitter only reads twitter name tags, so included that to.

I also thought maybe it was an SSL certificate error, so I installed one.. I'm running this on Vercel. If you type https://www.ecom-jobs.com, there seems to be a privacy error. But if you omit the www it works just fine. Here is my code for the job pages:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
import Head from "next/head";




function Job() {


  const [jobData, setJobData] = useState({
    company_name: "",
    company_url: "",
    company_description: "",
    city: "",
    postedat: "",
    job_position: "",
    job_category: "",
    logo: "",
    job_type: "",
    mission: "",
    location: "",
  });

  const router = useRouter();
  const { jobId } = router.query;

  useEffect( () => {
      if (jobId) {
       fetch("/api/jobs?id=" + jobId, {
          method: "GET",
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((jsonResponse) => setJobData(jsonResponse));
}}, [jobId]);



  let data =   
            {
            "@context": "https://schema.org/",
            "@type": "JobPosting",
            "title": `${jobData.job_position}`,
            "description": `${jobData.job_description}`,
            "hiringOrganization": {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": `${jobData.company_name}`,
                "sameAs": `${jobData.company_url}`,
            },
            "industry": `${jobData.job_category}`,
            "employmentType": "FULL_TIME",
            "datePosted": `${jobData.postedat}`,
            "validThrough": "",
            "jobLocation": {
                "@type": "Place",
                "address": {
                    "@type": "PostalAddress",
                    "streetAddress": "",
                    "addressLocality": "",
                    "postalCode": "",
                    "addressCountry": `${jobData.location}`
                }
            },
            "responsibilities": `${jobData.job_requirements}`,
            }

            

  function getDate() {
    let date_1 = new Date(jobData.postedat);
    let date_2 = new Date();

    let difference = date_1.getTime() - date_2.getTime();
    let TotalDays = Math.ceil((difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) * -1);

    if (TotalDays === 0) {
      return "Today";
    } else if (TotalDays === 1) {
      return `${TotalDays} day ago`;
    } else if (TotalDays > 1 && TotalDays < 30) {
      return `${TotalDays} days ago`;
    } else if (TotalDays >= 30 && TotalDays <= 60) {
      return "1 month ago";
    } else if (TotalDays >= 60 && TotalDays <= 90) {
      return "2 months ago";
    } else if (TotalDays >= 90 && TotalDays <= 120) {
      return "3 months ago";
    }
  }




// For job position ("Digital Marketing Manager") at company ("Henkel") it prints henkel-digital-marketing-manager-636630c71c719c263177f82a



  return (
    
    <div className="bg-gray-100 pb-10">
 <Head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>{`${jobData.job_position} | ${jobData.company_name}`}</title>
       
       
 
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content={`https://ecom-jobs.com/job/${jobData.jobUrl}`}/>
<meta property="og:title" content={`${jobData.job_position}`}/>
<meta property="og:image" content={`https://ecom-jobs.com/job/${jobData.logo}`}/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630"/>
<meta property="og:description" content={`${jobData.job_position}`}/>

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="ecom-jobs.com"/>
<meta name="twitter:url" content={`https://ecom-jobs.com/job/${jobData.jobUrl}`}/>
<meta name="twitter:text:title" content={`${jobData.job_position}`}/>
<meta name="twitter:text:description" content={`${jobData.job_position}`}/>
<meta name="twitter:image" content={`https://ecom-jobs.com/job/${jobData.logo}`}/>
</Head>

      {/* <NextSeo
      title={`${jobData.job_position} | ${jobData.company_name}`}
      description={`${jobData.job_position} available at ${jobData.company_name}`}
      canonical={`https://www.ecom-jobs.com/job/${jobData.jobUrl}`}
      openGraph={{
        type: "website",
        url: `https://www.ecom-jobs.com/job/${jobData.jobUrl}`,
        title: "hello",
        description: `this finally`,
        locale: 'en_EN',
        siteName: 'EcomJobs',
      }}
      twitter={{
        handle: '@ecomjobs_',
        site: 'ecom-jobs.com',
        cardType: 'summary_large_image',
      }}
  
    /> */}
      <Helmet>
      (<script className='structured-data-list' type="application/ld+json">{JSON.stringify(data)}</script>)
      </Helmet> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demos.creative-tim.com/notus-js/assets/styles/tailwind.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demos.creative-tim.com/notus-js/assets/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"/>

<main class="profile-page">
  <section class="relative block  h-500-px">
    <div class="absolute top-0 w-full h-full bg-center bg-cover" >
      
    </div>
    
  </section>
  <section class="relative">
    <div class="container mx-auto  px-4">
      <div class="relative flex flex-col min-w-0 break-words bg-white w-full mb-6 shadow-xl rounded-lg -mt-96">
        
          <div>
            
        
          
         
          <div class="mt-4 ml-6">

          <img src={`/images/${jobData.logo}`} alt="..." class="my-10 border-4  max-w-120-px"/>
          
          <a
                          target="_blank"
                          href={jobData.application_url}
                            class="flex float-right w-auto text-xs px-10 mr-4 lg:text-lg  -mt-20 rounded-full lg:pr-20 lg:pl-20   py-4  text-base  font-semibold text-white transition-all duration-200 bg-[#17614A] border border-transparent rounded-lg hover:bg-[#114031] focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-600"
                        >
                           Apply Now
                        </a>
                   
       

          <a href={`/company/${jobData.company_id}`}><h2 class="text-3xl my-4 text-black font-bold">{jobData.company_name}</h2></a>
       

            <div class="text-sm leading-normal  text-blueGray-400 font-bold uppercase">
              <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt mr-2 text-lg text-blueGray-400"></i>
             {jobData.city} {jobData.location}
            </div>
            

 
            <div class=" text-blueGray-600 my-2">
              <i class="fas fa-briefcase mr-2 text-lg text-blueGray-400"></i><a href={jobData.company_url} className="text-sky-400">{jobData.company_url}</a>
            </div>
          
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="text-center">
          <h2 className="sm:text-2xl lg:text-5xl my-4 mx-auto font-bold underline ">{jobData.job_position}</h2>
          <h3 className="my-1 text-md lg:text-xl text-[#6879a5]">  {jobData.job_category}  •   {jobData.job_type} • {getDate()}</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-10 py-10 border-t border-blueGray-200 text-center">
         
            <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
              <div class="w-full lg:w-9/12 px-4">
              

              <p>{jobData.company_description}</p>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
           
            <p>{jobData.job_description}</p>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
           
            <p>{jobData.job_requirements}</p>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            

<a
     target="_blank"
    href={jobData.application_url}
    class="inline-flex relative items-center justify-center w-full sm:w-auto px-8 py-3 sm:text-sm text-base sm:py-3.5 font-semibold text-white transition-all duration-200 bg-[#17614A] border border-transparent rounded-lg  hover:bg-[#114031] focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-600"
>
   Apply Now
</a>


            
               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </section>
</main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Job;
```

Comment: User-agent: facebookexternalhit
Disallow:

User-agent: Twitterbot
Disallow:

(my robots.txt file)

Comment: That's because you're fetching the metadata (`jobData`) on the client-side, it won't be available to crawlers if it's not present on the server response (see page source). Fetch the data on the server using `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`. See [Page content is not showing in page source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028991/page-content-is-not-showing-in-page-source).